# Archipack errors in Blender 2.90; cannot get the thumbnails to load; tried everything

Tags: python, rendering, archipack-add-on

I am using a 2012 miniMAC; Catalina OS 10.15.7; Blender 2.90.

In Blender I have called up archipack, tried rendering the thumbs, which I though was working; Pointed the file directory where the archipack marlib blend should be and still get the following error messages when I select door or window.  Ironically, the wall loads just fine.

Here is the error message:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/archipack/archipack_preset.py", line 475, in invoke
    self.menu = PresetMenu(context, self.preset_subdir)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/archipack/archipack_preset.py", line 222, in __init__
    self.make_menuitem(filepath)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/archipack/archipack_preset.py", line 299, in make_menuitem
    image.colorspace_settings.name = 'Raw'
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "Raw" not found in ('AppleP3 Filmic Log Encoding', 'AppleP3 sRGB OETF', 'BT.1886 EOTF', 'BT.1886 Filmic Log Encoding', 'Filmic Log Encoding', 'Linear', 'Non-Colour Data', 'sRGB OETF')

location: <unknown location>:-1
```
````

Comment: can you go to "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/archipack/"  
 
right click on archipack_preset.py and press open with (prefferable) a code editor, or else word or notepad. And go to line 299. And copy some of the code there so we can see it.

Comment: You have installed a custom OCIO config that doesn't contain a view transform called "RAW" and archipack doesn't use [`node.image.colorspace_settings.is_data = True`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ColorManagedInputColorspaceSettings.html#bpy.types.ColorManagedInputColorspaceSettings.is_data) to pick the correct color space. For a similar issue and how it was fixed, see [ticket 363 of BlenderGIS](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues/363).

Comment: You may want to report this on Blender's bug tracker or add a comment to this [ticket 137 on Archipack's GitHub repository](https://github.com/s-leger/archipack/issues/137).